# How to Decide on Which Browsers Versions My WebSite should be Supported?

Tags: browser

We have to create a Testing Strategy around which all browser version our website be supporting. What Factors should we keep in mind to take this decision. We are looking for decisions like.
 When should the Testing Happen for browser Support?
 What all browsers should we Test With?
 How to be future ready?

Any insights will surely help.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice i can give you here is... "Know your clients". In this case, ¿who are your visitors?.

In most cases they are the ones who are going to tell you your limits. Indeed its great if you can use the most actual tools and see your work running on the latest versions of major browsers but in my experience this doesn't happen that often.

So my advice here is: Use the most recent tools and technologies that allow all of your users to see you. This might affect some or your decisions even on designing, so keeping browsers in mind is a concern you should have from the start.

If we talk about browsers... chrome, firefox safari and edge are going to be probably your first headaches, but again, keep in mind your visitors. Internet Explorer is there but with microsoft running for Edge...

Apart from being mobile friendly and keeping your users and their experience as your first focus I can't give you any other advice.

Hope any of this helps and sorry for my bad english.